# 'Bone-idle' - what is the origin of the meaning?

Tags: etymology, idioms

[Phrases.org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bone-idle.html) quotes Robert Forby in his glossary *The Vocabulary Of East Anglia*, 1830, commenting that the entry falls short of mentioning the actual wording 'bone-idle' :

> Bone-lazy, bone-sore, bone-tired, adj. so lazy, sore, or tired, that the laziness, the soreness, or the fatigue, seem to have penetrated the very bones.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/106562#eid39524469) tells me that the two earliest uses of ['lazy bones'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/106562#eid39524469) are :

> 1593   G. Harvey Pierces Supererogation 185   Was..legierdemane a sloweworme, or Viuacitie a lasie-bones.
>
> 1600   N. Breton Pasquils Mad-cap (Grosart) 12/2   Go tell the Labourers, that the lazie bones That will not worke, must seeke the beggar's gaines.

However the first uses of ['bone idle'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21294?redirectedFrom=bone+idle#eid16830785) are attributed by the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21294?redirectedFrom=bone+idle#eid16830785) to Thomas Carlyle and Rudyard Kipling :

> 1836   T. Carlyle New Lett. (1904) I. 8   For the last three weeks I have been going what you call bone-idle.
>
> 1891   R. Kipling Light that Failed vi. 98   Bone-idle, is he? Careless, and touched in the temper?

I am intrigued as to how bones can be either 'lazy' or 'idle'. It is muscles that are the active constituents of limbs. Bones are moved by muscles.

Is the origin due to the concept of just the depth of idleness, that there is nothing deeper in a limb than a bone ?

Or is there some other original meaning to the idiom ?

Note : There is a mention of 'bone idle' in an answer to a closed question but the answer gives no information about the origin of the expression.

Comment: The idiom is likely an evolution of a metaphor, 'down to the bones', used as an intensifier to mean 'down to the very heart'. 'Bones' often has this connotation of centrality and heart, as seen in phrases such as 'bare-bones', 'close to the bone' and 'feel in his bones'.

Comment: Look here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bone_idle

Comment: I don't understand the title. It sounds like you are looking for synonyms of or even other pairs including 'bones' and being tired. But your text does not sound  not like that. Can you fix the title?

Comment: @HotLicks The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bone+idle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbone%20idle%3B%2Cc0) shows that BrE and AmE are equivalent and the usage rises from around 1880.

Comment: @Mitch Fixed as requested.

Comment: I suspect the most common ***bone-[adjective]*** version today is probably ***bone-dry*** - for which the full OED's first citation is Forby's *The Vocabulary Of East Anglia* as referenced by OP here.

Comment: @HotLicks: Overall prevalence for ***bone-idle*** has been pretty constant since it first gained real traction around the turn of the last century, but if you toggle AmE/BrE corpuses in [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bone-idle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbone%20-%20idle%3B%2Cc0) you'll see it's still 3-4 times more common in BrE. I've used it all my life (mostly spent in Sussex, UK South-East), but I never knew until now that it originated in East Anglia.

Comment: @NigelJ - Actually, it's about 4 times more common in British English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Oxford Dictionary of Word Origin*  says that the idea suggested by the expression *bone idle*  is that of being  idle all through to the bone.

***[Bone idle](https://books.google.it/books?id=J4i3zV4vnBAC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=bone%20idle%20origin&source=bl&ots=aFu7TOtNym&sig=dbXuTsNBgLGwEG5EHnXcQn5pjDI&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipz4-X0Z7cAhWE_KQKHfU7DxA4ChDoATACegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=bone%20idle%20origin&f=false):***
(old-fashioned, British English, informal)

> very lazy
>
> - Word Origin:
>   early 19th cent.: expressing idle through to the bone.

In ***[A Glossary of Words Pertaining to the Dialect of Mid-Yorshire and Holderness, Issues 1-2](https://books.google.it/books?id=Xfg3AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA32&dq=%22bone%20idle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1qumK1Z7cAhWODuwKHetbAwsQ6AEIUzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22bone%20idle%22&f=false)***  by C. Clough Robinson, they also suggest a possible origin from ***born idle***:

> Bone-idle, E. and N., adj. thoroughly lazy. ***There appears to be some doubt as to the origin of this word bone, whether it means idle even to the bones, or born idle***; in the E. it would appear to refer to the former, as they have a  saying “*He is idle tiv his  varray backbeean*”, while in the Noth it is frequently used in the latter sense, i.e. constitutionally idle from birth, in the same way as it is said  that Cap. Cook was a born sailor or Burns was a born poet.

An early citation of bone-idle is from “*[Fair Rosamond, or, The days of King Henry II: an historical romance](https://books.google.it/books?id=EWkpAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA245&dq=%22bone%20idle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirqMv66J7cAhUpsaQKHe_JBLIQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22bone%20idle%22&f=false)*” by [Thomas Miller](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Miller_(poet)), 1839:

> Marry i thou mayest work; — ***all these bone-idle fellows find thee out***. But I should not matter it so much, an' they needed it ; but when I think of their tithes, and their orchards, and their cattle, and their fish-ponds, and the money they have paid for masses, ....